# XSL: Get variable data without exslt:node-set

Tags: php, xslt

Using native XSL lib in PHP. Is it possible to get a node value inside a variable without having to call it through exslt:node-set every time.... it long and ugly.

```
<xsl:variable name="mydata">
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
</xsl:variable>


<!-- How currently being done -->
<xsl:value-of select="exslt:node-set($mydata)/foo" />


<!-- I want to be able to do this -->
<xsl:value-of select="$mydata/foo" />
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation when the `xxx:node-set()` is not needed and for a complete code example. :)

Comment: Using this technique I found two extra things that might prove important. document('') doesn't refer to included stylesheets, so you can't really place your variable somewhere in your includes. Second, should you need to combine several inline-built nodesets, you can't use variables, but can use several elements in a custom namespace to separate them from xsl constructs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="mydata">
>  <foo>1</foo>
>  <bar>2</bar>
> </xsl:variable>
>
> <!-- How currently being done -->
> <xsl:value-of select="exslt:node-set($mydata)/foo" />
>
> <!-- I want to be able to do this -->
> <xsl:value-of select="$mydata/foo" />
> ```

**If the contents of the variable is statically defined, then it *is* possible** to access it from an XPath expression without the use of the `xxx:node-set()` extension function.

**Example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="mydata">
  <foo>1</foo>
  <bar>2</bar>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='mydata']/bar"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2
```

Comment: @Flack: Your answer was only partially wrong. If the content of the variable isn't static (that is, it is generated as result of xslt instructions), then `xxx:node-set()` *must* be applied for the children node(s) to become accessible to XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call `node-set` just once. Convert the variable into a node-set type:

```
<!-- do it once at the beginning -->
<xsl:variable name="mydatans" select="exslt:node-set($mydata)" />
<!-- anytime you need: -->
<xsl:value-of select="$mydatans/foo" />
```